# Can't retrieve all Mongo Documents with a query - only some are returned

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, php-mongodb

I'm having trouble retrieving all documents that match a query on MongoDB. I'm using PHP.

Here's a quick test:

```
## Document 1   

{
   "_id": ObjectId("4ea80a1eb73e26ef1500cc9e"),
   "search": {
   "0": "clothing",
   "1": "golden",
    ....etc

## Document 2
{
   "_id": ObjectId("4ea81e78b73e26ef15339c65"),
   "search": {
     "0": "and",
     "1": "belt",
     "2": "brown",
     "3": "golden",
    ...etc

## query
$search = array('golden');
$products = Products::all( array('search'=>array('$in'=> $search ))) // only document 1 is returned.
//this is a quick test. in the end I'd like to have:
$search = array('golden', 'belt'); //document 2 is returned
```

Documents are created from a PHP array, with 'search' being a sorted and uniqued array of string elements:
    sort($search);
    $search = array_unique($search);

```
$new->setProperty('search', $search);
```

I'm pretty new to Mongo, but I don't understand why, if the syntax of my document is not correct, then one is returned instead of none.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what in PHP, but this works:

```
> db.items.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ea98d0fa287fedc0281feee"), "name" : "first", "keywords" : [ "one", "two", "three", "four" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ea98d1aa287fedc0281feef"), "name" : "first", "keywords" : [ "two", "three", "four", "five" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ea98d23a287fedc0281fef0"), "name" : "first", "keywords" : [ "four", "five", "six" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ea99243a287fedc0281fef1"), "name" : "first", "keywords" : [ "five", "six" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ea99247a287fedc0281fef2"), "name" : "first", "keywords" : [ "five", "six", "seven" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ea99273a287fedc0281fef3"), "name" : "first", "keywords" : [ "one", "two", "seven" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ea9927aa287fedc0281fef4"), "name" : "first", "keywords" : [ "one", "two", "seven" ] }
> db.items.find({$or:[{keywords:"four"},{keywords:"five"}]})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ea98d0fa287fedc0281feee"), "name" : "first", "keywords" : [ "one", "two", "three", "four" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ea98d1aa287fedc0281feef"), "name" : "first", "keywords" : [ "two", "three", "four", "five" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ea98d23a287fedc0281fef0"), "name" : "first", "keywords" : [ "four", "five", "six" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ea99243a287fedc0281fef1"), "name" : "first", "keywords" : [ "five", "six" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ea99247a287fedc0281fef2"), "name" : "first", "keywords" : [ "five", "six", "seven" ] }
> db.items.find({keywords:{$in:["four","five"]}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ea98d0fa287fedc0281feee"), "name" : "first", "keywords" : [ "one", "two", "three", "four" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ea98d1aa287fedc0281feef"), "name" : "first", "keywords" : [ "two", "three", "four", "five" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ea98d23a287fedc0281fef0"), "name" : "first", "keywords" : [ "four", "five", "six" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ea99243a287fedc0281fef1"), "name" : "first", "keywords" : [ "five", "six" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4ea99247a287fedc0281fef2"), "name" : "first", "keywords" : [ "five", "six", "seven" ] }
```

Comment: Tried like this, still no luck:                 $products = Products::all( array('$or' => array(array('search'=>"golden")))); - only some documents are returned, but not document 2.

Comment: This is the same if I execute my query in the shell or via a web-admin like RockMongo